# Plotting a route between user's location and specified location on Google MapKit in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, google-maps, mapkit

Hey guy,
On my iPhone project, I built a Google Map using MapKit, and specified a location of my company on the map. Now I want to add a little feature where my google map will plot a route between a user's location to my company's location. So far this is the code I used to specify the location of my company

```
#import "GoogleMap.h"
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation GoogleMap

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    variable1 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                         pathForResource:@"NewYorkAreas" 
                                                         ofType:@"plist"]];

    double minLat = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@min.latitude"] doubleValue];
    double maxLat = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@max.latitude"] doubleValue];
    double minLon = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@min.longitude"] doubleValue];
    double maxLon = [[variable1 valueForKeyPath:@"@max.longitude"] doubleValue];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = (maxLat + minLat) / 2.0;
    region.center.longitude = (maxLon + minLon) / 2.0;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = (maxLat - minLat) * 1.05;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxLon - minLon) * 1.05;
    map.region = region;

    for (NSDictionary *newYorkAreasDict in variable1){
        MyAnnotation *annotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithDictionary:newYorkAreasDict];
        [map addAnnotation:annotation];
        [annotation release];
    }
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{

    if (map.userLocation == annotation){
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *identifier = @"MY_IDENTIFIER";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (annotationView == nil){
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                       reuseIdentifier:identifier] 
                          autorelease];
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    }
    return annotationView;
}
```

So now, I want to implement the user's location and plot a route between the user's location and my company, but I have no clue how to code it, so I hope someone can help me out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be you would need to get the GPS coordinates for the route, then you could use an MKOverlayView.

check [this](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136) out for more info